# Te-form by itself「コロナウイルスがうつった人のことも考えて」

Tags: meaning, て-form

What does the te-form mean here by itself?

> コロナウイルスがうつった人のことも考えて

Edit: The context is a newspaper headline: 大学の入学試験「コロナウイルスがうつった人のことも考えて」Does a te-request really make sense in this context?

Comment: This is when more context will help.

Comment: @EddieKal Not 100% sure, but very likely that this NHK easy news article is the source: https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10013425551000/k10013425551000.html

Comment: NHK News Easy is news, but calling it a newspaper with no other context is a little misleading. It's intentionally written to be easy to read, so the language used does not necessarily have to conform to standard newspaper conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a short form of 「～てください(te-kudasai)」 and kudasai is omitted. So the whole sentence should be 「コロナウイルスがうつった人のことも考えてください。」, which means "Please think about the people who got infected with the coronavirus."

I think this usage of Te-form is more common in conversation than writing, such as 「助けて！(tasukete="Help (me)!")」 or 「明日来て。(asita kite="Come tomorrow.")」, probably because it's short and easy to say. On the other hand, Te-kudasai is more formal, polite, and common in writing.

Comment: Hello, please see my comment!

Comment: I've read the NHK news web. Hmm, I think there are two possibilities.

**(1)** 文部科学省は、大学に対して、「コロナウイルスがうつった人のことも考えてください。」と言った。
  Ministry of education tells universities to "think about the people(=students) who got infected with coronavirus."
  
**(2)** 大学の入学試験は、コロナウイルスがうつった人のことも考えて実施される予定だ。
  University exam will be took place taking into consideration the people(=students) who got infected with coronavirus.

I can't be sure whether (1) or (2) is correct, but I think in either case the main point of the news is that university exam will take COVID positive students into consideration.

Answer (score 3):

Context would help, but I would suggest considering the possibility of it being a request, leaving a following ください or more informally くれ unsaid. The sentence therefore means something like "(Please) Think about all the people the corona virus has infected."

Comment: Hello, please see my comment!